# Data not being fetched until user exits application but yet has already saved it to the database

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api2

Even though My save has indeed updated the record for some reason my players dont update until the customer exits his app then the player appears without any intervention

```
public async Task<List<Players>> GetALLPlayers()
{
    List<Players> _result = new List<Players>();
    EnsureHttpClientCreated();
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.BaseUrl + Constants.ApiSegmant + 
    Constants.GetAllPlayers, string.Empty));

    await AddAuthenicationHeader();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

       var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
       _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Players>>(content);
    }

    return _result.ToList();
}
```

This is how am creating up my http client

```
private HttpClient httpClient;
private HttpClientHandler _httpClientHandler;    

public HttpApi()
{
    _timeout = Timeout ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
    CreateHttpClient();
    db = new ThehockeylABSqlLiteDB();
}

private void CreateHttpClient()
{
    _httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | 
      DecompressionMethods.GZip
    };

    httpClient = new HttpClient(_httpClientHandler, false)
    {
        Timeout = _timeout
    };

    

  httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent
  .ParseAdd(ClientUserAgent);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Constants.BaseUrl))
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.BaseUrl);
    }

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(MediaTypeJson));
}

private void EnsureHttpClientCreated()
{
    if (httpClient == null)
    {
        CreateHttpClient();
    }
}
```

My get all players method is as such.

```
private readonly IPlayerInterface db;
public PlayerController(IPlayerInterface classes)
{

   db = classes;
}

[HttpGet("GetALLPlayers")]
[Authorize]
public List<Players> GetALlPlayers()
{
   try
     {
      var test = db.GetAllPlayers();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {

     }

   return db.GetAllPlayers();
}
```

My Service call

```
public class PlayerService : IPlayerInterface
{
  AppDBContext db;
  public PlayerService(AppDBContext dBContext)
  {
    db = dBContext;

  }

 public List<Players> GetAllPlayers()
 {
   return db.Players.Where(w => w.IsActive == true && w.IsDeleted 
    == false).Include(i => i.Notes).ToList();
 }
```

..... rest of service class
}
This is my DI injection for addscoped.

```
services.AddScoped<IPlayerInterface, PlayerService>();
```

This is how am binding to my grid.

```
public async Task<int> BindGrid()
{
    var players =await api.GetALLPlayers();
    dgPlayers.ItemsSource = null;
    dgPlayers.ItemsSource = players; //here stil has the old count why when am doing the 
                                     same call out to players
    playersCount.Text = $"Total Players {players.Count().ToString()}";
    return 1;
}
```

I think what I need to do is add AsNoTracking  to my query to by pass ef caching am I right ?

Comment: without understanding how this code flows together its difficult to say whats wrong.  Is `BindGrid` being called again after you have saved your data?  Are you expecting that to happen automatically without needing to refresh the data?

Comment: Correct as always @Jason Bindgrjnd is called just after the save its going back out to the api so am scratching my head here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a global varible `myPlayers` as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<YourItem>  myPlayers{ get; set; }
```

and initialize `myPlayers` as follows:

```
myPlayers = new ObservableCollection<YourItem>();
```

And in method `BindGrid`,try to convert your `players`  to type `ObservableCollection<YourItem>`:

```
List<YourItem> players = new List<YourItem>();
players =await api.GetALLPlayers();

//convert players  to ObservableCollection<T>
myPlayers.Clear();
foreach (var item in players) {
   myPlayers.Add(item);
}
```

//here you can assgin `myPlayers`  to `dgPlayers.ItemsSource`

```
dgPlayers.ItemsSource = myPlayers;
```

Note:

If we define type `ObservableCollection<YourItem> myPlayers` for `myPlayers`, once an item  is removed or added in `myPlayers`, the UI will refresh automatically.

Comment: But that could be very slow if u have hundreds of players in the object ?

Comment: Then you can consider using paging load.